# Integrating multivariate normal in Python/R

Tags: python, r, math, scipy, statistics

I am trying to find the covariance of a multivariate normal on some interval [a,b] via integration. The function is "int_a^b int_a^b f(x, y) (x - mu_X) (y - mu_Y) dx dy" where f(x, y) = (normal pdf) / (normal cdf on a to b). See [tmvtnorm](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010/RJ-2010-005/RJ-2010-005.pdf) for more information on the formula.

When I set a = -inf and b = inf, I get correctly Cov(X_1, X_2) = 0.8. SciPy gives the same result.

```
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 10
mp.pretty = True

def integrate(mu=mp.matrix([0.5,0.5]),
              cov=mp.matrix([[1, 0.8],[0.8, 2]]),
              a=[-1, -mp.inf],
              b=[0.5, 4]):

    def f2(x, y):
        v = mp.matrix([x - mu[0], y - mu[1]])
        pdf = -0.5 * v.T * cov **-1 * v
        return mp.exp(pdf[0])

    c = mp.quad(f2, [a[0], b[0]], [a[1], b[1]])

    def f(x, y):
        v = mp.matrix([x - mu[0], y - mu[1]])
        pdf = -0.5 * v.T * cov **-1 * v
        return mp.exp(pdf[0]) * (x - mu[0]) * (y - mu[1])

    return mp.quad(f, [a[0], b[0]], [a[1], b[1]]) / c

print(integrate(a=[-mp.inf, -mp.inf], b=[mp.inf, mp.inf])) # 0.8
```

Now I change the bounds of integration and verify it with R:

```
install.packages("tmvtnorm")
library(tmvtnorm)

mtmvnorm(mean=c(0.5, 0.5), sigma=matrix(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 2), 2, 2), lower=c(-1, -Inf), upper=c(0.5, 4))

$tmean
[1] -0.1220891161  0.0004821634

$tvar
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.1646990 0.1312234
[2,] 0.1312234 1.4575935
```

But Python returns `print(integrate(a=[-1, -mp.inf], b=[0.5, 4])) # 0.4419680296` instead of 0.1312234.

Where is my mistake?

**Update**

As was noted in the comments, one problem is that I used the mean of the normal distribution. After fixing this bug, there is a problem with numerical stability (Gaussian quadrature?). Any comments are welcome!

```
from mpmath import mp
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

mp.dps = 10
mp.pretty = True

# mean formula from
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution
def mean(a, b, mu, sigma):
    alpha = (a - mu)/sigma
    beta = (b - mu)/sigma
    numerator = norm.pdf(alpha) - norm.pdf(beta)
    denominator = norm.cdf(beta) - norm.cdf(alpha)

    return mu + (numerator/denominator) * sigma

def integrate(mu=np.array([0.5,0.5]),
              cov=np.array([[1, 0.1],[0.1, 1]]),
              a=[-5, -5],
              b=[5, 5]):
    sigmas = np.sqrt(cov)
    mu_0 = mean(a[0], b[0], mu[0], sigmas[0,0])
    mu_1 = mean(a[1], b[1], mu[1], sigmas[1,1])
    cov = mp.matrix(cov)

    def f2(x, y):
        v = mp.matrix([x - mu_0, y - mu_1])
        pdf = -0.5 * v.T * cov **-1 * v
        return mp.exp(pdf[0])

    c = mp.quad(f2, [a[0], b[0]], [a[1], b[1]])

    def f(x, y):
        v = mp.matrix([x - mu_0, y - mu_1])
        pdf = -0.5 * v.T * cov **-1 * v
        return mp.exp(pdf[0]) * (x - mu_0) * (y - mu_1)

    return mp.quad(f, [a[0], b[0]], [a[1], b[1]]) / c, mu_0, mu_1

print(integrate(a=[-5, -3], b=[5, 3])) # cov=0.09541323939, R says 0.09524736
print(integrate(a=[-5+10, -3+10], b=[5+10, 3+10])) # cov=0.5297249671, R says 0.0001140013
print(integrate(a=[0, 0], b=[np.infty, np.infty])) # cov=0.132181971, R says 0.02536199
print(integrate(a=[-np.infty, -np.infty], b=[np.infty, np.infty])) # cov=0.1, R says 0.1
```

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't see where the discrepancy lies, however, shouldn't there be a factor of 1/determinant(cov) in there somewhere? Likewise 1/(2 pi) or something? I guess maybe those terms cancel out, however, my advice is to leave them in, in order to make it easier to understand what's going on. When you work with a simplified integrand, you have to remember why it doesn't look right every time you go to check a computed value. A minor aside -- try printing the normalizing factor c.

Comment: Are you using the mean vector mu[] of the normal distribution? If you are wanting to calculate the central moments of the truncated distribution you should use the mean vector of the truncated distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! One bug was really that I used the wrong mean vector. However, I still do not get the correct results.